# Insert large numbers of images into Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle10g

I would like to insert 10's of millions of images into oracle database using java, but if I do that, what type of storage or sql exceptions may occur?

Comment: BLOB is the most used datatype.

Comment: If it is really tens of millions of images (what size are they?): Is it a requirement to store the images themselves into the database? Another approach would be to store them on a file system and access them through e.g. a web server, and store only the meta data (access path/URL etc.) in the database

Comment: As Andreas says, you might choose to store them in the database, or outside the db on a filesystem. The choice may come down to whether you think the images will remain largely static, or if you need transactional control over them; also, your backup/restore process may have a bearing on the decision as well.

Comment: keeping the images outside the database makes the system more fragile of course. You're introducing a point of failure in every image, if it gets deleted, renamed, moved, without the database being updated you now have a corrupt dataset.